# How to set form_validation to required for Files in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, file-upload

I am trying to set `form_validation` for `FILES` in codeigniter. I have written the following code. Its working fine for `input fields` but its not working properly for `input files`.

VIEW

```
    <tr><th>Price</th><td>         <input type="text"  name="price"> </td></tr>              
    <tr><th>Color</th><td>         <input type="text"  name="color"> </td></tr>                
    <tr><th>Size</th><td>          <input type="text"  name="size"> </td></tr>                 




    <tr><th>Front Image</th><td>    
                    <input type="file" name="userfile_1">          </td></tr> 


   <tr><th>Right Sleeves Images</th><td>
                    <input type="file" name="userfile_2">          </td></tr> 


    <tr><th>Left Sleeves Images</th><td>
                    <input type="file" name="userfile_3"></td></tr>         


     <tr><th>Back Image</th><td>
                    <input type="file" name="userfile_4">          </td></tr> 

    <tr><th>Submit </th><td><input type="submit"    value="Insert"> </td></tr>
```

CONTROLLER

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('product_name','Product Name','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('price','Price','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('color', 'Color','required');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile_1','Image 1','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile_2','Image 2','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile_3','Image 3','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile_4','Image4','required');
```

I have loaded all the required libraries and Helpers. It works fine for input fields but for images it says `Image 1 is required`, even after i upload image1, same thing happens with the rest of the files.

Kindly Guide me how to resolve this problem.

Thanks
Taha

Comment: The filename is `<input type="file" name="userfile_1">` but you are checking for `file`. Unless this is a typo after copy/paste, I believe this is the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try as:

```
if (empty($_FILES['userfile_1']['name']))
{
$this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile_1','Image 1','required');
}
if (empty($_FILES['userfile_2']['name']))
{
$this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile_2','Image 2','required');
}
if (empty($_FILES['userfile_3']['name']))
{
$this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile_3','Image 3','required');
}
if (empty($_FILES['userfile_4']['name']))
{
$this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile_4','Image4','required');
}
```